# AngularJS Routing to Multiple Start Pages

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url-routing, dashboard

I am trying to make an app where I have a home page, and a dashboard that has a separate route.  If I use ng-route, I will only be able to add stuff onto my homepage.

Basically, I'm asking how can I have it so when I got to http://example.com/#/features  And then go to http://example.com/#/dashboard/control , be able to still use ng-route on my dashboard page, instead of injecting it into my home page.  Is there something I can add to my app.js, or will I have to make an entirely new app.js for my dashboard (which is what I was thinking I have to do)

I hope this made sense, I've always had trouble explaining things like this :P .

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of using `ng-route` use `ui-router`,`ui-router` will provide you better control over navigation

Its can be structured like

```
.state(login)
.state(login.forgotpassword)
.state(dashboard)
.state(dashboard.list)
.state(dashboard.user)
```

as you see you can have navigation control over two different state.